# Триггер на добавление роли пользователю - discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Имеется задача: если пользователю добавляют определенную роль, то выводился бы его ник.  В [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) я смог найти только `on_guild_role_create`, `on_guild_role_update` и `on_guild_role_delete`.

Как можно **обнаруживать** добавление роли пользователю?

Comment: Ваш код? Ваши попытки?

Comment: Я сейчас пытаюсь найти триггер (если это можно так назвать) из  discord.py на добавление роли пользователю. Думаю, можно сохранять список  с людьми у которых есть роль и если изменяется, то делать действия. Но это скорее кастыли, чем реализация

Comment: Обратите внимание на [on_member_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update)

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал про эту